# I want to assign a json string to a scope variable without list name in json?

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

How to assign the this to scope variable in angular js?

```
{[{“1”:”a”,”2”:”b”},{“3”:”c”}]}
```

Comment: I am looking to declare above json using $scope.Please provide the declaeation using example scope variable $scope.a

Comment: Should it start  and  end with { } or [ ]

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking, but I think this is what you want

```
$scope.someVariableName = {
    someArray: [{“1”:”a”},{”2”:”b”},{“3”:”c”}] 
}
```

To access the data here

```
$scope.someVariableName.someArrayName[1]
```

would return the object {”2”:”b”}

```
$scope.someVariableName.someArrayName[1].2
```

or

```
$scope.someVariableName.someArrayName[1][2]
```

would return the string "b"

or you could just have the array

```
$scope.someArrayName = [{“1”:”a”},{”2”:”b”},{“3”:”c”}]
```

so that

```
$scope.someArrayName[2]
```

would return the object {”2”:”b”}